# Using MahApps.Metro, how can we change fonts for title of MetroWindow?

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

As shown below, by default, the [MetroWindow](https://mahapps.com/docs/controls/metrowindow) of [MahApps.Metro](https://mahapps.com/) shows the title of the Window in uppercase, background of the title as blue and the forecolor as white.

**Question**: How can we change the above properties using `MahApps.Metro`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the properties of the `MetroWindow` which changes the title bar in MahApps v2.4.x

- `TitleCharacterCasing`: Changes the character casing with the CharacterCasing enumeration values
- `TitleForeground`: Gets or sets the brush used for the titlebar's foreground
- `WindowTitleBrush`: Gets or sets the brush used for the Window's title bar
- `NonActiveWindowTitleBrush`: Gets or sets the brush used for the Window's non-active title bar